# How to find the variables that are asssigned to HTML elements

Tags: jquery-ui, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to write a plugin for a website that uses jquery widget library.

In the given example they asking the above:

> you should always use the variables assigned to elements and never the element ID’s

I know I can access to variables through inspect mode and than print to the console

```
document.getelementbyid('elementid')
```

I still cant find the variable name assigned to the element I'm looking for.

Is it the right way to do it? is there en efficient way to do it?

Thank a lot!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

To find the variables assigned to HTML elements, you need to look at the JavaScript code that is associated with the HTML file. Here are the steps to follow:

1. Open the HTML file in a code editor or text editor that supports syntax highlighting for HTML and JavaScript.
2. Look for the  tags in the HTML file. The JavaScript code will be contained within these tags.
3. Scan the JavaScript code for any variable declarations that are associated with HTML elements. Typically, these declarations will use the "document.getElementById" method to select the HTML element and assign it to a variable.

For example, if you have an HTML element with an id of "myElement", the associated JavaScript code might look something like this:

javascript code

**var myVar = document.getElementById("myElement");**

This code selects the HTML element with the id of "myElement" and assigns it to a variable called "myVar".

This code selects the HTML element with the id of "myElement" and assigns it to a variable called "myVar".

4. Look for any references to the variable in the JavaScript code to see how it is being used. You should be able to see how the variable is used to manipulate the associated HTML element.

By following these steps, you should be able to find the variables that are assigned to HTML elements in your code.